# Size definition of strcat() function

Tags: c, string, size, strcat

The question is why should I define size of string (`string[]` should be `string[some-number]`)
When the program is as following it gives me `Abort trap: 6`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char buffer1[] = "computer";
  char string[]="program";
  strcat( buffer1, string );
  printf( "buffer1 = %s\n", buffer1 );

}
```

This is the program from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm it works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
   char str1[12] = "Hello";
   char str2[12] = "World";
   char str3[12];
   int  len ;

   /* copy str1 into str3 */
   strcpy(str3, str1);
   printf("strcpy( str3, str1) :  %s\n", str3 );

   /* concatenates str1 and str2 */
   strcat( str1, str2);
   printf("strcat( str1, str2):   %s\n", str1 );

   /* total lenghth of str1 after concatenation */
   len = strlen(str1);
   printf("strlen(str1) :  %d\n", len );

   return 0;
}
```

What is the mistake? Even if I define all of the sizes of strings in my program, my code still gives `Abort trap:6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `strcat` is buffer overflowing `buffer1` which can hold only `strlen("computer")+1` bytes. ommitting array size does not mean "dynamic" array! When you specify the size of the array, you are reserving as many bytes as you want: again you need to avoid bufferoverflow of course.

So,

```
 strcpy(str3, str1);
```

and

```
 strcat( str1, str2);
```

are ok since `str3` size is enough for `str1`, and `str1` is enough for `strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1`, i.e. exactly 11: 5 (hello) + 5 (world) + 1 (terminator). The magic number 12 was choosen with a reason, big enough to hold both strings and a terminator.

#### About C strings

C-strings are array of chars where the last is "null", `'\0'`, i.e. they are array of chars where the last one is 0. This terminator is needed so that string related functions can understand where the string ends.

If it happens that a null byte is found in the middle of a string, from the point of view of C string functions, the string will end at that point. E.g.

```
char buffer1[] = "computer\0program";
// array: { 'c', 'o', ... '\0', 'p', 'r', 'o', .., 'm', '\0' }

// ...
printf("%s\n", buffer1);
```

will print `computer` only. But at this point the buffer will be big enough to hold computer and program, a terminator (and another extra byte), since the compiler computed the size of the char array considering the literal sequence of characters which syntactically ends at the second `"`.

But for all C-string functions, the string contained in `buffer1` is `computer`. Note also that `sizeof buffer1` will give the correct size of the buffer, i.e. 17, opposed to the result of `strlen(buffer1)` which is just 8.

Comment: Why it is `+2` not `+1`? since we're only using single `\0` after end of the `buffer1`?

Comment: 1 is enough indeed. I was wrong. But even number are nicer. Or maybe they thought to add a space between Hello and World

Comment: However, when I define `buffer1` enough to hold them both (`16`), size of `string` should be still `+1` (`8`), why? Is that because we are using `\0` of `string`, not of the `buffer1`?

Comment: all C string are null-terminated and must be null terminated in order to make string functions work properly (they need to know where the string ends). So, if you want to concatenate two strings of length n1 and n2, you need n1+n2+1 bytes. When you want enough room for just the string n1, you need n1+1 bytes; for the string 2, you need n2+1 byte. And so on

Comment: if you don't "write" into `string`, you have not to worry about how many bytes the buffer is long. Since you let the compiler choose the correct size, `string` will be able to hold `strlen(string)  + 1` bytes, as said, no more. Since a string must be null-terminated, the longest string you can memorize is `strlen("program")` byte long. But you can use that buffer to store an extra byte, if you are not dealing with C strings, e.g. `memcpy(string, "program1", 8)` would be ok, but then you cant use `string` as a C-string.

Answer (score 2):

From the man page of strcat:

DESCRIPTION
       The strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string, overwriting the termi‐
       nating null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and then adds a terminating null byte.  The
       strings may not overlap, and the **dest string must have enough space for the result**.  If
       dest is not large enough, program behavior is  unpredictable;  buffer  overruns  are  a
       favorite avenue for attacking secure programs.

When you declare your string, the compiler allocate the size of your initial string to be 9 (resp. 8) for the buffer1 (resp. string) (includin '\0').

Thus, strcat will result in 9 - 1 + 8 (i.e. 16 bytes) but only 9 are available.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `strcat` is used to store the result, so it must have enough space for the concatenated string.

In your code:

```
char buffer1[] = "computer";
```

is equivalent to:

```
char buffer1[9] = "computer";
```

defines a char array with just enough space for the string `"computer"`, but not enough space for the result.

Comment: This means that strcat() function can be applied NOT to combine 2 strings, but to put the second string INSIDE 1st string at the `\0`? Is it correct?

Comment: @MotherLand Yes, `strcat` puts the second string inside the first string at the previous `\0`, and puts a new `\0` in the new end.

Comment: however if i define size of 1st array enough to hold both `buffer1` and `string`. The size of `string` should be `+1` for `\0` but we don't use it?

Answer (score 1):

```
char buffer1[] = "computer";
```

Creates a buffer big enough to hold 9 characters (strlen("Hello" + `1` byte for `\0`)). If you write anymore data to it what you end up with **is Undefined behavior (UB)**. This is what happens when you do a `strcat`.
UB means the program might crash or show literally any behavior. You are rather lucky that a program with UB crashes because it does not need to, but if it does atleast there is a indication of something wrong in it. Most of the times programs with UB will continue running correctly and crash when you least expect or want them to.